# How to create muliple war file from one Maven jersey REST API project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, rest, maven, eclipse-plugin

How to create multiple war files from one maven eclipse Jersey Rest API project? As i have multiple Rest APIs in this project. I want to have one war file per each Rest API. How to do? As i don't want to use multi module maven project.

Comment: Maven generally supports a single deliverable per module, and it encourages that by making it rather difficult to color outside those lines. So, for example, if you're project packaging is defined as "war" then, Maven makes it really easy to produce a single war. If you have multiple APIs, and they're all in the same project, you may be better served by refactoring to support 1 API per project, than trying to get one project to generate multiple war files.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is using Maven's `executions` feature (i.e. "run" any plugin, multiple times, in your case `maven-war-plugin`).

So basically you "run" `maven-war-plugin` multiple times, and configure it differently for each war you want to make. Below is an example taken from SO (you need to tailor the `configuration` section for each `execution`.

*Please be aware, that this is considered "last-resort" build design, and it is still advisable to use multi-module.*

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>list</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <warName>myProj-list.war</warName>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <filters>
                    <filter>src/main/filters/list.properties</filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>  
        ...
        <!-- more executions -->
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```